# understanding syb boilerplate elimination

Tags: generics, haskell, boilerplate

In the example given in http://web.archive.org/web/20080622204226/http://www.cs.vu.nl/boilerplate/

```
-- Increase salary by percentage
increase :: Float -> Company -> Company
increase k = everywhere (mkT (incS k))

-- "interesting" code for increase
incS :: Float -> Salary -> Salary
incS k (S s) = S (s * (1+k))
```

how come increase function compiles without binding anything for the first Company mentioned in its type signature.

Is it something like assigning to a partial function? Why is it done like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's the same concept as partial application. The line is a shorter (but arguably less clear) equivalent of

```
increase k c = everywhere (mkT (incS k)) c
```

As `everywhere` takes two parameters but is only given one, the type of `everywhere (mkT (incS k))` is `Company -> Company`. Because this is exactly what `increase k` returns for each Float k, the resulting type of `increase` is `Float -> Company -> Company`.

Comment: It might be less clear at first, but it is one of the fundamental properties of curried functional programs and considered good practice by every experienced functional programmer.